# force Hostapd to make connection with wrong password

Tags: c, linux, wifi, wpa, hostapd

hi i'm trying to make a penetration testing platform and i need to edit hostapd application to make connection with wrong password.

my try :
i changed wpa_auth.c :

```
if (!ok) {
        wpa_auth_logger(sm->wpa_auth, sm->addr, LOGGER_DEBUG,
                "invalid MIC in msg 2/4 of 4-Way Handshake");
        if (psk_found)
            wpa_auth_psk_failure_report(sm->wpa_auth, sm->addr);
        return;
    }
```

to :

```
if (ok) {
        wpa_auth_logger(sm->wpa_auth, sm->addr, LOGGER_DEBUG,
                "invalid MIC in msg 2/4 of 4-Way Handshake");
        if (psk_found)
            wpa_auth_psk_failure_report(sm->wpa_auth, sm->addr);
        return;
    }
```

because i get "invalid MIC in msg 2/4 of 4-Way Handshake" when i enter a wrong password.

anyone can help me to make this penetration testing platform?

thanks.